# Is there a way to perform a full system encryption of Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, security

**My Question is:** I'd like to use my Raspbian encrypted, just like it is standard on Debian, Ubuntu or other Linux-Distros.

**My Problem:** Technically, you are not installing Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi or a SD-Card, instead you are copying a prepared image from the internet. Is there a way to perform an encryption of the whole system? (maybe without `/boot`)

Comment: Wouldn't truecrypt do the job? http://www.truecrypt.org/ you can choose if you want full system encryption or just parts of the partition.

Comment: @hustlerinc TrueCrypt can only boot Windows from an encrypted disk/partition. While you could encrypt the Raspbian partition, you wouldn't be able to boot from it anymore.

Comment: Raspbian is Debian, and you should be able to use it to do the same things -- just not via an installer, obviously, which will complicate encrypting the entire system.  AFAICT they use dm-crypt: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).  Some of it's main features (from the site) include:

> - Creates a virtual encrypted disk within a file and mounts it as a real disk.
> - Encrypts an entire partition or storage device such as USB flash drive or hard drive.
> - Encryption is automatic, real-time (on-the-fly) and transparent.
> - Parallelization and pipelining allow data to be read and written as fast as if the drive was not encrypted.
> - Encryption can be hardware-accelerated on modern processors.
> - Provides plausible deniability, in case an adversary forces you to reveal the password: 
>     Hidden volume (steganography) and hidden operating system.

Other Raspberry Pi forum users have tried it and [found it to work pretty well](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=6225).  There are some instructions on that forum post on how to do it yourself.  The explanation is pretty lengthy, so I won't post that here.

---

Also, [Berryboot OS offers LUKS full disk encryption out of the box](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=244508#p244508).

Answer (score 3):

the full system encryption will consume too much processing power for decryption and re-encryption, so you'll effectively bring your processor down to the knees just by reading or writing a file, rendering your system too slow and useless.

you should reconsider your requirements and maybe encrypt your user files only, that's faster and easier. you may follow the [following link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome) for detailed explanation.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Most of the SD will be occupied with freely available content. The content you would want to encrypt would be a small % of that. I found this useful https://itsfoss.com/password-protect-folder-linux/

Answer (score 1):

Kali Linux, a Debian-derived distribution, documents Raspberry Pi Disc Encryption at https://docs.kali.org/kali-dojo/04-raspberry-pi-with-luks-disk-encryption

Quoted excerpt from 2019-04-30:

> Birds Eye View of the Disk Encryption Process The process described
>   below was tried and tested successfully on a Raspberry Pi B+ and a
>   Raspberry Pi 2/3 (henceforth collectively called “RPi”). but it should
>   be trivial to port these instructions to any ARM device running Kali.
>   Before we begin, let’s take a minute to quickly describe what we’ll be
>   doing – as while this process is not complicated, it is involved. This
>   is basically our spiel:
>
> We download the required Kali RPi image and dd it to an SD card. We
>   chroot to the RPi image and install/update several files in
>   preparation for our crypted boot. We create an initramfs file which
>   includes Dropbear and freshly generated SSH keys. We rsync the
>   modified rootfs to a temporary backup location and then delete the
>   rootfs partition from the SD card. We then recreate an encrypted
>   partition to which we restore the root partition data. That’s it! If
>   all goes well, the RPi will boot and then LUKS will kick in and ask
>   for a password to decrypt the root drive, while simultaneously opening
>   a Dropbear SSH session through which you can SSH in and provide the
>   boot decryption password. Oh yeah, did we mention this image also has
>   LUKS NUKE capabilities?

previous answer linked to: https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux/raspberry-pi-luks-disk-encryption/

Comment: Summarize the information from the link in your post.

Comment: @jimmont - Yu should probably submit your own updated answer, rather than updating a very old post

Comment: We have encouraged people to fill in the blanks on link-only answers,  although otherwise I would agree w/ GOL.