# How to encrypt whole file system of Raspbian Buster

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, encryption

We have done a project with Raspberry Pi 3B. I have read something about filesystem encryption of the Raspberry Pi/Raspbian. Also, I read [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10076/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-full-system-encryption-of-raspbian) which answered years ago (too old!). I didn't understand the ways. My purpose is to prevent spoiling system files of Raspbian.

In [this link](https://community.zymbit.com/t/encrypting-your-root-file-system-on-raspberry-pi-using-luks-dm-crypt/150) they suggest a module/board which I do not prefer using that.

Situation details:

- A camera connected by a USB port with no additional driver.
- A USB sound card connected with no additional driver.
- An Arduino connected by USB (RS232).
- Some relay connected by GPIO pinout.
- Raspberry Pi 3B.
- Raspbian Buster.

The thing that I'm looking for is a procedure that helps me to encrypt whole (`/boot` isn't important) the SD-Card.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not tried this but https://www.zymbit.com/zymkey/ I don't know what happens if you need to fix a bug!

Comment: You can reverse engineer something without ever having to violate any security; the only way to prevent it is to never allow anyone to use the software.  Of course, there are specific reverse engineering techniques that have more specific requirements and are preventable.  In any case, that stuff isn't really on topic here.  What would be are details concrete to the Pi, eg., how to encrypt a filesystem, etc.

Comment: Is good ole LUKS not an option for the rpi platform? Too processor intensive?

Comment: @CoderMike Bugs isn't important. As I searched, `zymbit` has a hardware module. Is that right?

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks, I've edited the question.

Comment: @0xSheepdog What's ole LUKS?

Comment: @M.Rostami [Linux Unified Key Setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) disk encryption. I'm pretty good with Linux, fairly new to RPi. No idea if it would work effectively on RPi.